# AJAX call to Java character encoding

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I currently have 2 different jsp pages where both do calls to a java application. Currently in only one of them the character encoding works good.

Page A does:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _root + myPage,
    data: myData,
    success: mySuccessHandler,
    error: myErrorHandler});
```

Page B does:

```
$.post(_root + page, data, successHandler).error(errorHandler);
```

Inside the java application I'm using this code, there are 2 separate functions, but the only difference is the parameter name A uses "answerdata" and B uses "data":

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("answerdata"), "UTF-8"));
```

Both jsp pages have the data encapsulated inside a form:

```
<form id="answerdata" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Both also have this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

And only the page A, where it doesn't work has, but removing this doesn't have any effect:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
```

I've been through some pages on stackoverflow, but the only answer that worked for one of my pages so far was the

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

But that only worked for page B

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(new String(request.getParameter("answerdata").getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```